# Reddit bot: problems retrieving comments

Tags: python, praw

I've been trying to create a simple Reddit bot using Python with PRAW. However, I have a problem retrieving comments from the subreddit. My "test_word" was not being found, so I printed the retrieved comments to see what the looked like and they look like these five here for example:

ebkiuyr
ebkiuwd
ebkiuqe
ebkiuoz
ebkiue8

Since I'm getting weird letter combinations instead of comments, I'm guessing my use of PRAW is incorrect?

Code I used is below:

```
import praw
import time

processed = []
counter = 0

def run():
    # log in
    redd = praw.Reddit(client_id = client_id,
                        client_secret = client_secret,
                        username = username,
                        password = password,
                        user_agent = useragent)

    # get comments
    for comment in redd.subreddit('testingground4bots').comments(limit=25):

        # test to see what comments look like
        print(comment)

        # reply if phrase found
        if "test_word" in comment.body.lower() and comment.id not in processed:
            comment.reply("Test successful!")
            processed.append(comment.id)
            print("replied to comment with id {}".format(comment.id))

while True:
    run()
    time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: Looks like those are comment IDs - notice that if you fill in one of them as the comment ID in this link, you can view all its info. So, looks like you're getting comment IDs, not comments themselves: https://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?id=t1_ebkiuyr

Comment: Referencing [this](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/comment.html#praw.models.Comment), it appears that you need `comment.body` and what you are getting is `comment.id`.

Comment: @RandomDavis Ah I see, thanks! Thanks for the useful link, too :)